# "Site unreachable" when using asset parallelization with Cloudflare CDN

Tags: dns, performance, cdn, static-content

I use WordPress site with CDN (Cloudflare). I want to serve static files(images, js, and css) from a different static cookieless domain.

I create subdomains in my DNS, but I can't add images or other static files to these.  When I try to parallelize downloads with the help of plugin it doesn't work.  I think it's because of the CDN.

When I enter the site URL, Google chrome says the site is unreachable.

Comment: Can you add more information?   The actual domain name (and subdomains) would help.   Also, how are you trying to add static files to these?  How are you uploading them?